# How to use printer on server

Tags: c#

I download .zip file from outlook then send pdf files to printer. It works on my local machine while compiling, However I setup published app on server, it downloads .zip file from outlook and open it but it can not send to printer . How can I handle that?

**This is my code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
    exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail@", "password");
    exchange.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

    if (exchange != null)
    {
        SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
        FindItemsResults<Item> result = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, new ItemView(1));

        foreach (Item item in result)
        {           
            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id);

            message.IsRead = true;
            message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

            List<Attachment> zipList = message.Attachments.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(".zip")).ToList();

            foreach (Attachment Attachment in zipList)
            {            
                if (Attachment is FileAttachment)
                {
                    FileAttachment f = Attachment as FileAttachment;

                    f.Load("C:\\TEST\\" + f.Name);

                    string zipPath = @"C:\TEST\" + f.Name;
                    string extractPath = @"C:\TEST\" + Path.GetRandomFileName();

                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);

                    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.pdf",
                                 SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                    foreach (string path in filePaths)
                    {                      
                        SendToPrinter(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



static void SendToPrinter(string path)
{
    try
    {              
        var printerName = "EPSON L310 Series";



            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
            info.Verb = "PrintTo";
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                p.Kill();
    }         
    catch (Exception ex)
    {              
        Console.WriteLine("error:", ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }    
}
```

As I said, everything is work fine  but printer not working. I can print pdf manually I mean machine works. Also this app works on my local machine

[image]

Comment: So you run this code on the server and can I assume that you have already checked if the "EPSON L310 Series" printer is available there?

Comment: it is available there I know that because on server I can print manually  with "EPSON L310 Series" @Steve

Comment: When the app runs on the server what user account is it running under?

Comment: as administrator @IanMercer

Comment: Please update the question to show the **exact** value of `path` (from the `Watch` or `Immediate Window`).

Comment: You have an account called "administrator" and you log in using that account and can print and the server application runs under the exact same account as what? An NT Service? or do you mean you are running it from command line logged in as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
info.UseShellExecute = false;
```

to:

```
info.UseShellExecute = true;
```

since the `path` is a path to a PDF file, not an executable.

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> When you use the operating system shell to start processes, you can
>   start any document (which is any registered file type associated with
>   an executable that has a default open action) and perform operations
>   on the file, such as printing, by using the Process object. When
>   UseShellExecute is false, you can start only executables by using the
>   Process object.

Additionally:

> If you set the WindowStyle to ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
>   UseShellExecute must be set to true.

You are using `Hidden` - thus `UseShellExecute` must be `true`.

Comment: This seems reasonable, but why then does the application work locally?

Comment: Sometimes doing the wrong thing works, under some circumstances. That doesn't make it the right thing to do. The docs are the authority.